# I need to recover BCH

Tags: bitcoin-cash, multibit-hd

So I had some BTC in a Multibit HD wallet (from 2014) and in October 2017 I transferred it to an Electrum wallet as I had learned that MultibitHD was no longer being supported. I just learned about BCH, and was wondering if there was some way I could gain access to the BCH. Unfortunately, I do not know the seed phrase for my now-empty multibit HD wallet, but I do have everything for the Electrum wallet.

UPDATE: I think I found the seed phrase for the MultibitHD wallet!

Answer (score 1):

To recover your bitcoin cash, you need the access to the private keys of the wallet where your bitcoins were before the fork, which happened at the beginning of August 2017.

If you have withdrawn your bitcoins from your Multibit wallet in October 2017, then you can recover bitcoin cash from your Multibit wallet only. If you have no access to your Multibit wallet anymore, then your bitcoin cash coins are lost. I am sorry.

**Update:**

In case you still have access to your MB seed, I would recommend you the following simple steps:

1. Follow [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-KcY6KUVnY&feature=youtu.be) to import your MB HD seed into Electrum. Check if there are still any bitcoins on that wallet and withdraw them to another bitcoin wallet. Just to be sure that you won't lose them during the further process. This will not affect your BCH
2. Follow the official Electrum [Recommendation on how to redeem Bitcoin Cash](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt). Short version below:

> 2.1 Install Electron Cash.
>
> 2.2 Import your MB seed into Electron Cash.
>
> 2.3 Enjoy your coins and send your promised bitcoin cash reward to :) 3AxGUDoXKtz4w6fba6HPrp8j8XFmSwFCoE

*Note1:* For a more safer approach, read the recommendation.

*Note2:* In case you will not be able to import your MB HD seed into Electron Cash, first export another seed or private key from your Electrum wallet, which you created in step 1 and use it instead of the MB HD seed.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can see non-zero balances on your old addresses with BCH blockexplorer like http://blockdozer.com/insight/

But you do not have seed of your old MultibitHD wallet.

Sorry, man. These coins are lost for you and everyone.

Comment: See my comment to henk below. I have the seed phrase now.